# .htaccess .html redirects

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been asked to set up a redirect on a website.

Currently the website redirects allows you to visit http://www.site.co.uk/test instead of /test.html

The code being used is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to keep this behaviour, but also redirect the .html extension to the non html version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#redirect .html version
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ (/[^\ ]+)\.html\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```